# Convert NSData to a NSString returns random characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I am working on a `bluetooth iOS` project and have managed to get some data from the `bluetooth` device.
However, I am struggling to convert this data into something useful, such as an `NSString`. Whenever I try to `NSLog` the `NSString` that was converted from the `NSData` received, it is a bunch of `gibberish`. The output is:

```
ēဥ၆䄀
```

The bluetooth device is a heart monitor from a manufacturer in Asia and they have provided the protocol reference on how to make calls to the device. This one thing they mention in the protocol reference:

```
The PC send 16-byte packets to the device, then the device sent back the 16-byte packets. Except for some special commands, all others can use this communication mode.
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I have tried everything I know, including every single encoding in the apple docs as well as both `initWithData` and `initWithBytes`. Thanks!

```
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
         error:(NSError *)error {
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"erorr in read is %@", error.description);
    return;
}
NSData *data= characteristic.value;
 NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Value from device is %@", myString); //OUTPUT IS ēဥ၆䄀

}
```

Comment: Are the "16 bit packets" supposed to represent human readable text?

Comment: @Joni I believe it is. I am trying to read the value on the heart rate monitor. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: As Joni mentioned: you don't say what is the specification of those 16-byte packets. Most BT protocols don't send HR data over the radio since that would be a huge waste or time. Those 16-bytes could be 4 32-bit double variables (IEEE 754) or something. You can probably link to this BT device via serial console (TeraTerm,CoolTerm) and chek this.

Comment: Try putting this line before your `NSLog` and post the printout: `NSLog (@"raw data - %d: %@",data.length,data);`

Comment: @rokjarc Thank you for the reply. I did what you suggested and it returns: <01131025 10464100 00000000 000000e0>

Comment: @rokjarc For example, if I want to read the number of steps (also has a pedometer) for that day, this is what the protocol says: Get the steps :
Command format: 0x4B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CRC Function: PC read target steps on the device
Command response:
Check right and execute OK, then return: 0x4B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CRC Check error and execute Fail, then return: 0xCB AA BB CC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CRC Response description : AA BB CC is the target steps value,3 bytes,high byte in front.

Comment: Yep, this are not humanly readable (ASCII or anything else) values. You will need a specification of data packet.

Comment: @rokjarc Sorry I'm not quite understanding what you mean. You seem to know much about this. Would you be willing to chat about it for a few minutes in the chat room? I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43731/discussion-between-teddy13-and-rokjarc)

Comment: Ok, i can join you in about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is a *string* of raw data that can't be directly converted into a human readable string - unless you consider hex-representation to be human readable :)

To make sense of this data you need to either have a protocol specification at hand or prepare for hours (sometimes) days of reverse-engineering.

This byte-sequence can be composed of multiple values formatted in standard (float [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`...) or even proprietary formats.

One important thing to consider when communicating with the outside world is also [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (ie: does the 'biggest' byte in multi-byte format come first or last).

There are many ways to manipulate this data. To get the raw array of bytes you could do:

```
NSData *rxData = ...
uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t *)[rxData bytes];
```

And then if (for example) first byte tells you what type of payload the string holds you can switch like:

```
switch (bytes[0])
{
    case 0x00:
        //first byte 0x00: do the parsing
        break;

    case 0x01:
        //first byte 0x01: do the parsing
        break;

    // ...

    default:
        break;
}
```

Here would be an example of parsing data that consists of:

byte 0: byte holding some bit-coded flags
bytes 1,2,3,4: 32-bit float
bytes 5,6: uint16_t

```
bool bitFlag0;
bool bitFlag1;
bool bitFlag2;
bool bitFlag3;

uint8_t firstByte;
float theFloat;
uint16_t theInteger;

NSData *rxData = ...
uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t *)[rxData bytes];

// getting the flags
firstByte = bytes[0];

bitFlag0 = firstByte & 0x01;
bitFlag1 = firstByte & 0x02;
bitFlag2 = firstByte & 0x04;
bitFlag3 = firstByte & 0x08;

//getting the float

[[rxData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 4)] getBytes:&theFloat length:sizeof(float)];
NSLog (@"the float is &.2f",theFloat);

//getting the unsigned integer

[[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 2)] getBytes:&theInteger length:sizeof(uint16_t)];
NSLog (@"the integer is %u",theInteger);
```

One note: depending on the endianness you might need to reverse the 4-float or the 2-uint16_t bytes before converting them. Converting this byte arrays can also be done with unions.

```
union bytesToFloat
{
    uint8_t b[4];
    float f;
};
```

and then:

```
bytesToFloat conv;

//float would be written on bytes b1b2b3b4 in protocol
conv.b[0] = bytes[1]; //or bytes[4] .. endianness!
conv.b[1] = bytes[2]; //or bytes[3] .. endianness!
conv.b[2] = bytes[3]; //or bytes[2] .. endianness!
conv.b[3] = bytes[4]; //or bytes[1] .. endianness!

theFloat = conv.f,
```

If for example you know that byte6 and byte7 represent an `uint16_t` value you can calculate it from raw bytes:

```
value = uint16_t((bytes[6]<<8)+bytes[7]);
```

or (again - endianness):

```
value = uint16_t((bytes[7]<<8)+bytes[6]);
```

One more note: using simply `sizeof(float)` is a bit risky since float can be 32-bit on one platform and 64-bit on another.

Comment: Thanks! Hope it will be usefull :)